# Loading Multiple Forms In a panel

Tags: forms

I have a main form the has 2 panels on it with a splitter bar. 
The right panel holds a graphic area (Panel2)

The left panel (Panel1) is where I want to load different forms using a variable for the forms.
Based on menu picks I have something like 40 different forms.

I thought I could do the following where I pass in the form  using ByRef but I get an error on this line that is fMyForm that says "Type fMyForm Is not defined"

```
frm = New fMyForm() With {.TopLevel = False, _
               .Parent = Me.splitContainerControl.Panel1}
```

Can any one help show me where I am going wrong

```
Public Sub FormMgrOpen(fMyForm As Form)

    Dim the_hwnd As Long
    Dim form_is_open As Boolean
    Dim frm As Form

    Me.splitContainerControl.Panel1.Controls.Clear()

    frm = New fMyForm() With {.TopLevel = False, _
           .Parent = Me.splitContainerControl.Panel1}

    splitContainerControl.PanelVisibility = SplitPanelVisibility.Both

    frm.Show()    

    splitContainerControl.SplitterPosition = frm.Width 

    Me.splitContainerControl.Panel1.Refresh() 

    frm.Size = Me.splitContainerControl.Panel1.Size 


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`fMyForm` is a local variable, so i don't think it should have parenthesis!
try this one:

```
 frm = fMyForm With {.TopLevel = False, _
            .Parent = Me.splitContainerControl.Panel1}
```

I don't know VB, so forgive me if it is wrong in syntax! :)